# Pass dynamic content to the react table sub component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

I am using react table v6 for grid purposes. I am trying to implement a subcomponent where in the data to this sub component needs to be passed dynamically. This sub component should expand and collapse on click of arrows. I have tried the following , but the sub component is not rendering any data. I am creating a wrapper for this, the data to the subcomponent should be passed dynamically based on the source data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-subcompoentn-sk14i?file=/src/DataGrid.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

export default class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  renderSubComponent = original => {
    console.log(original);
    return (
      original.nested &&
      original.nested.map((i, key) => (
        <React.Fragment key={key}>
          <div>{i.name}</div>
          <div>{i.value}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactTable
        data={this.props.data}
        columns={this.props.columns}
        SubComponent={this.renderSubComponent}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DataGrid from "./DataGrid";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      columns: [],
      allData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  getData = () => {
    const data = [
      {
        firstName: "Jack",
        status: "Submitted",
        nested: [
          {
            name: "test1",
            value: "NA"
          },
          {
            name: "test2",
            value: "NA"
          }
        ],
        age: "14"
      },
      {
        firstName: "Simon",
        status: "Pending",
        nested: [
          {
            name: "test3",
            value: "NA"
          },
          {
            name: "test4",
            value: "Go"
          }
        ],
        age: "15"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  getColumns = () => {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  onClickRow = rowInfo => {
    this.setState({ allData: rowInfo }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.allData);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DataGrid
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          rowClicked={this.onClickRow}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: where are you passing variable original to  renderSubComponent  function

Comment: its implicitly passed, you could check the console.log inside the function

Comment: ohh yeah  i mis-understood,its a function got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try spread the argument and it will work :

```
   ...
   renderSubComponent = ({original}) => {
   ...
```